# iOS Charts show only one chart segment

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I try to setup a pie chart from `Charts` library with two items. My code if following

```
lazy var pieChart : PieChartView = {
    let pie = PieChartView()
    pie.data?.setValueTextColor(UIColor.abClear())
    pie.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    pie.legend.enabled = false
    return pie
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb"]
    let unitsSold = [10.0, 10.0]

    setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChart.data = pieChartData

    pieChartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
}
```

The problem is that chart draws only one item - blue one. Looks like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it resolves your issues :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. The problem is the values you are setting for `x` and `y` in `ChartDataEntry`. Change your code in the function `setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double])`:

```
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
    let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])//ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
```